# Making my `CustomDialogFragment` generic

Tags: java, android, generics, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

So i want to make my `CustomArrayAdapter` class generic.

CustomDialogFragmentNotGeneric:

```
public class CustomDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
{
    TextView listViewItemTextView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    ListView dialogListView;
    String[] items = {"Hello","Hello there","Hi","Hi there"};

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, container,false);

        getDialog().setTitle("Choose an option"); // Set dialog title

        listViewItemTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_view_item_text_view_id);
        dialogListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_list_view_id);

        getDialog().setTitle("Opening Words"); // Setting dialog title


        CustomArrayAdapter customArrayAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getActivity(), items);
        dialogListView.setAdapter(customArrayAdapter);

        dialogListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), items[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

It's not generic because of the `String[] itemm =` line.
So instead of building *a lot* of classes that in each there will be a different `String[] item`, how do i make that generic?

dialog.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/dialog_list_view_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

MyCustomArrayAdapter class:

```
package com.example.predesignedmails;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    Context context;
    String[] items;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] items) 
    {
        super(context, R.layout.list_view_row,items);

        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            this.layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = this.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_row,parent,false);
        }

        TextView rowTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_text_view_id);

        rowTextView.setText(this.items[position]);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

list_view_row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/row_text_view_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have put a lot of effort into this post. Please help me guys. Thanks.

**EDIT**

my activity layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.predesignedmails.LoveMailsActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/love_email_emai_to_send_to_text_view_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/emai_to_send_to_text_view_text"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/opening_words_list_view_header_color"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/love_email_email_to_send_to_edit_text_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/emai_to_send_to_edit_text_hint"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="@color/selection_text_color"
    android:layout_below="@id/love_email_emai_to_send_to_text_view_id"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/love_email_opening_words_header_text_view_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/love_email_opening_words_text_view_text"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/opening_words_list_view_header_color"
    android:layout_below="@id/love_email_email_to_send_to_edit_text_id"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/love_email_opening_words_text_view_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/initial_text"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="@color/selection_text_color"
    android:layout_below="@id/love_email_opening_words_header_text_view_id"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayAdapter` is already generic. Based on your current code, you can get rid of your entire `CustomArrayAdapter` class and simply use this constructor (replacing `String` with whatever type your items are):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
        R.layout.list_view_row, R.id.row_text_view_id, items);
```

If you plan to keep `CustomArrayAdapter`, you can declare it like this to keep the generics:

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {
    ...
}
```

Naturally you would use `T` instead of `String` wherever necessary.

Comment: The method with the array adapter gives me a NullPointerException on the `listView.setAdapter()` line. Possibly because i dont have a ListView view in my activity?

Comment: Based on the code I see, `R.layout.dialog` needs to have a ListView with `android:id="@+id/dialog_list_view_id"`

Comment: But it's in another layout. my `setContentView()` method doesnt contains a `ListView`.